# Last two element of list view is hiding

Tags: android, android-listview

I have designed layout in which I have listview which will display more than 200 names of list , at the bottom I have four button.

The problem is that last two element of list view are hiding behind that footer. I am not able to figure out. 
Any help is appreciated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/store_screen_action_bar"
        layout="@layout/action_bar" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/store_screen_lists"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/store_screen_action_bar"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="@drawable/divider_line"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" 
        />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" 
        /> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#c8d5e1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/store_screen_anouncement"
                android:layout_width="60dip"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
                android:paddingBottom="40dip"
                android:paddingLeft="30dip"
                android:paddingRight="20dip"
                android:paddingTop="40dip"
                android:src="@drawable/announcement" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/annoucement_text"
                android:textColor="#306190"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/store_screen_group"
                android:layout_width="60dip"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
                android:padding="20dip"
                android:src="@drawable/groups" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:text="@string/groups_text"
                android:textColor="#306190"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/store_screen_interupt_all"
                android:layout_width="60dip"
                android:layout_height="60dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
                android:padding="10dip"
                android:src="@drawable/interrupt" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/interrupt_text"
                android:textColor="#306190"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/store_screen_ear_box"
                    android:layout_width="60dip"
                    android:layout_height="60dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
                    android:padding="60dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/earbox" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:text="@string/earbox_text"
                    android:textColor="#306190"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/play_announcement_no_text"
                android:layout_width="25dip"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:background="@drawable/green_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/play_message_no_text"
                android:layout_width="25dip"
                android:layout_height="25dip"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                android:background="@drawable/red_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: and what is a root layout ?

Comment: root layout is RelativeLayout, I have posted the whole code

Comment: add id to the footer and move it above listview in xml(right after include) ... then in listview add android:above=footer_id

Comment: I have edited please have a look

Comment: Okay let me try Selvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these attributes to `ListView`:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/store_screen_action_bar"
android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
```

and set the `id` of your `LinearLayout` footer:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `android:layout_below="@id/list` for your footer

Comment: then footer will be invisible?

Comment: I guess your list and footer are overlapping so your last list-items are behind your footer. With this code you place your footer under your list. And yes, your footer will be visible